# WPF Databinding and cascading Converters?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, binding, converters

i wonder if it is possible to cascade converters when using wpf databinding.
e.g. something like

```
<SomeControl Visibility="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource firstConverter}, Converter={StaticResource secondConverter}}"/>
```

is it possible at all or do i have to create a custom converter that combines the functionality of converter A and B?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to use a **MultiBinding**, and bind twice to the same source, but with different converts on the single bindings. Something like:

```
<SomeControl>
    <SomeControl.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource combiningConverter}">
            <Binding Path="SomeProperty" Converter="{StaticResource firstConverter}"/>
            <Binding Path="SomeProperty" Converter="{StaticResource secondConverter}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </SomeControl.Visibility>
</SomeControl>
```

Then in '*combiningConverter*' you put the logic to combine the values coming from the two bindings.

Answer (score 18):

You may be looking for a solution similar to Josh Smith's "[Piping Value Converters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PipingValueConverters_WPF.aspx)".

In his article, he presents the following:

```
<local:ValueConverterGroup x:Key="statusDisplayNameGroup">
  <local:IntegerStringToProcessingStateConverter  />
  <local:EnumToDisplayNameConverter />
</local:ValueConverterGroup>
```

And then uses the multi-value converters as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Status, 
             Converter={StaticResource statusDisplayNameGroup}}" />
```

Hope this helps!