# How to boolean && two visibility converters

Tags: wpf, data-binding, converters

I have two separate converters for visibility, one based on whether a field has been updated and one based on whether a field is allowed to be seen.  I use the updatedField one for each text item on my page so that a star shows up next to an updated field.  But some text items only are visible to some users based on permission levels.

For example:

```
<Image Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyObject, Path=UpdatedFields, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource updatedFieldConverter}, ConverterParameter=FieldToTest}" Source="Properties:Resources.star_yellow" />
```

and

```
<TextBlock FontSize="21" Foreground="{DynamicResource LabelBrush}" Text="{x:Static Properties:Resources.Some_Text}" Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource allowedFields}, Path=Some_Text_Field, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}" />
```

My problem is that for the case of the permission-required fields I need to run both converters to determine if the star shows up.  Is there a way to do a boolean "And" on the results of two converters?

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594357/wpf-how-to-use-2-converters-in-1-binding) but it doesn't seem to allow for different sets of parameters to be passed into to the two different converters.

-------Update--------

I also tried to create a MultiValueConverter with this xaml

```
<Image Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Source="star_yellow.png">
   <Image.Visibility>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource combinedVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="FieldToTest" >
         <Binding ElementName="allowedFieldsModel" Path="Some_Text_Field" Mode="OneWay" />                        
         <Binding ElementName="MyObject" Path="UpdatedFields" Mode="OneWay" />
      </MultiBinding>
   </Image.Visibility>
</Image>
```

But when it enters the converter both values are "DependencyProperty.UnsetValue".  So I'm apparently doing something wrong here.

--------Solution---------

I had to modify to this, but then it worked.

```
<Image.Visibility>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource combinedVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="FieldToTest">
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource allowedFieldsModel}" Path="Some_Text_Field" />
        <Binding Path="MyObject.UpdatedFields" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Image.Visibility>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You could use a MultiBinding together with a short, hand made IMultiValueConverter.

**Example:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:MultiBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Converter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <CheckBox x:Name="Box1" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="Box2" />
    <TextBlock Text="Hidden Text">
        <TextBlock.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                <Binding ElementName="Box1"
                            Path="IsChecked" />
                <Binding ElementName="Box2"
                            Path="IsChecked" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Visibility>
    </TextBlock>                   
</StackPanel>
```

... and the converter ...

```
class MultiBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values,
                            Type targetType,
                            object parameter,
                            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool visible = true;
        foreach (object value in values)
            if (value is bool)
                visible = visible && (bool)value;

        if (visible)
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value,
                                Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Psiclopz: I've given an example. This works on MY machine =) Your case seems to be more complicated than that, but maybe it helps.

Comment: It almost worked for me, but like you said, my case was a bit more complicated.  I posted my solution above.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 34):

Late to the party here but an easier solution is to just wrap the control in another control. I prefer this to having lots of Converters that do different things.

```
<Border Visibility="{Binding Value1, Converter={convertersDF:Converter_ValueToVisibility}}">
 <ComboBox Visibility="{Binding Value2, Converter={convertersDF:Converter_ValueToVisibility}}"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: Briliant! No need to write extra class for such a simple thing!

Comment: From WPF chat - the consensus is that borders are the cheapest way to do something like this (instead of a StackPanel).

Answer (score 2):

One thing that came to mind is, perhaps, instead of two different boolean fields, a single bit field created by ORing together updatedField and allowedField.  Then you can have three value converters, all operating on the same field.

Or just calculate another field in your data model that does the ANDing there.  That's probably more efficient (in terms of runtime).

Comment: Can you provide more details on this?  I don't understand how you would do that in the xaml.

Comment: You don't do it at all in the xaml.

Comment: This goes against the separation of view and model. I'm sure runtime efficiency difference is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an array of two objects to the converter in the `ConverterParameter` - constructing the array in XAML.