# Binding a button's IsEnabled property to 2 checkbox IsChecked properties in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I would like to enable a button when either of the 2 check boxes are checked.
When neither of the check boxes are checked, the button should be inactive(IsEnabled = false)

It is possible to bind like this.

> IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox Path=IsChecked}"

But it works only for a single checkbox. I want to bind both the check boxes IsChecked properties to the IsEnabled property of button in XAML itself. (I know how to do using property changed in code)

I tried using Multi triggers.

```
            <Button.IsEnabled>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>                                                  <Binding ElementName="BlankmeasurementCheckBox" Path="IsChecked"/>
                     <Binding ElementName="MeasurementCheckBox" Path="IsChecked"/>
                  </MultiBinding.Bindings>
             </MultiBinding>
          </Button.IsEnabled>
```

But it doesn't seem to help. Could you please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post what have you tried....

Comment: the above code you posted will only set for one checkbox.

Comment: i have added.. please check

Comment: are you following mvvm pattern (is there any viewmodel or model, command etc.)

Comment: Yes I am following MVVM pattern. I was asking like if I can bind the property to 2 checkbox properties in XAML itself rather than writing code in view model

Comment: What you can do is,you can define two bool properties and bind it to the two checkboxes,then you  can  set the isEnabled on the canexecute method of the button`s command based on the properties.

Comment: I already know that method. I was asking like if I can do it in XAML similar to the following code?  
<Button.IsEnabled>
               <MultiBinding>
                   <MultiBinding.Bindings>                                                 > <Binding ElementName="BlankmeasurementCheckBox" Path="IsChecked"/>
                       <Binding ElementName="MeasurementCheckBox" >Path="IsChecked"/>
                   </MultiBinding.Bindings>
               </MultiBinding>
           </Button.IsEnabled>

Comment: You have to use a BooltoVisiblity Converter for that.
Let me post some code.

Comment: Have a look in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501970/how-to-boolean-two-visibility-converters)

Comment: @VishakhBabu See my anwer below and let me know whether it helped or not.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you GopiChandar. You could provide the exact solution as I expected. Thanks to Abhinav Sharma for also providing a helping hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `MultiDataTrigger` here.

Here is the sample code:

```
 <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <CheckBox Name="cbSampleYes" Content="Yes" />
        <CheckBox Name="cbSampleSure" Content="I'm sure" />
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="Verified" />                    
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbSampleYes, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbSampleSure, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Unverified" />
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you. The sample code works fine.
But I am still facing issues with the style.. Before the style was defined in the button ie within the <Button /> tag..

Now I changed it to inside the style(ie within the <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button"> tag). But the style still doesn't work. I need gray BG color and white FG color. But it doesn't work the way I need it to be.

Comment: @VishakhBabu I hope this answers for your question.  Pls create a separate question for others that are not related this thread.   Also, feel free to accept the answer if it resolves your question.  Thanks!