# WPF binding visibility

Tags: c#, wpf

I have label that shoul be visible when RadioButton `First` or `Second` `IsChecked=true` and Collapsed when `Third` or `Fourth` `IsChecked=false`. 
Is it only one way to do it pass name of the button to the converter and in converter decide should it be collapsed or visible?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <RadioButton Content="Visible" x:Name="First"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="Visible" x:Name="Second"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="Collapsed" x:Name="Third"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Collapsed" x:Name="Fourth"></RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
    <Label Content="Test" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Start with Binding the isSelected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement `IMultiValueConverter` and use it to bind `Visibility` to several values.
You can find example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501970/how-to-boolean-two-visibility-converters)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the MVVM pattern with a framework like [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com). Then in the View Model, you can have a property for LabelVisiblity that the Label binds to.

If the MVVM pattern is not an option, you could add events handlers for each CheckBox's Checked event. Then set the Visility there.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        option1.Checked += Option_Checked;
        option2.Checked += Option_Checked;
        option3.Checked += Option_Checked;
        option4.Checked += Option_Checked;
    }

    private void Option_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var option = (sender as RadioButton);
        if (option.Name == "option1" || option.Name == "option2")
            textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }
```